# How to toggle Bluetooth on/off in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been trying to get the status of Bluetooth in android through this code:
I instantiated `BluetoothAdapter` in `onCreate()` method...and called `blue.isEnabled()` like this

```
if(blue.isEnabled()){
....
}
```

But I kept getting this error..and yes I have declared all the permissions for `Bluetooth`

**Error Log**

```
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at com.emazdoor.remind.me.main.onClick(main.java:58)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-05 21:48:16.881: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please Help! Thanks

**Complete Code**

```
public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button CallButton, SMSButton, BirthdayButton, BusinessButton; 
    BluetoothAdapter b1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
        b1 = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        Initialiser();

    }

    private void Initialiser() {

        CallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CallButton);
        SMSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SMSButton);
        BirthdayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BirthdayButton);
        BusinessButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BusinessButton);


        CallButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        SMSButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        BirthdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        BusinessButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.CallButton:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, CallRemind.class));
        break;
    case R.id.SMSButton:
        Toast.makeText(this, "SMS Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SMSReminder.class));
        break;
    case R.id.BirthdayButton:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Birthday Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        b1.enable();
        break;
    case R.id.BusinessButton:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Business Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.layout_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` documentation:

```
Returns
the default local adapter, or null if Bluetooth is not supported on this hardware platform
```

Are you checking your code on an emulator?
Or maybe on a phone without bluetooth?

Comment: Yes checking it on emulator. Let me see the bluetooth support.

Comment: Deep voice: [Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) has *no bluetooth* support.

Comment: @YuvalGiveon  yup you guys are correct. Thanks for helping. I got have real device. :)